# Rewrite to case insensitive urls in CodeIgniter site?

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, case-sensitive, codeigniter-2

I'm using CodeIgniter for a web application, and now I have an urgent question: I just discovered that urls are case sensitive in Linux based servers, and I have just moved a site from Windows to Linux. This means links to the site don't work anymore where there are now all lower-case urls, which were not before.

Googling I found that you should be able to do something like this in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

But I tried that and it was not good at all...! Suddenly I got a big ugly error page staring at me instead, saying that there must be something wrong with the Tomcat server or something like that. Needless to say I removed those lines immediately!

But why didn't it work then, and what should I do instead?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually found out that it was quite easy, surprised that no one answered this (perhaps it isn't the correct way, but I would think so...):

I just added some routes in the routes.php file in the config folder:

$route['About/Contact'] = "about/contact";

And so on...

Comment: This isn't a great solution because you're creating multiple routes for every casing of the same route key.  This is why the suggestion was to handle it with modrewrite - so that your routes can be expressed once regardless of the casing used in the request.

Answer (score 8):

Code igniter supports regular expressions - if you'd like to be explicit in the definition of your routes, define them in this fashion to be case insensitive:

```
$route['(?i)(about\/contact)'] = 'about/contact';
```

Comment: Here, shows url is user typed name.the thing I want is route should be case insensitive and showing url should be case sensitive.Can I do this thing?

Comment: In my snippet, the left side of the assignment handles case insensitivity of the request.  The right side of the assignment specifies the URL to which the request will be routed.  So a request for about/contact in any case will route to about/contact in lowercase.  I believe you should try specifying the routed URL in your desired casing.  It should work.

Answer (score 0):

If case insensitive routes are required, do below changes to URI.php

Location of File: `system/core/URI.php`

Find `$this->_parse_request_uri() and replace it with strtolower($this->_parse_request_uri())`